# Add more levels to menu

Tags: menus

I have a menu with more than three levels.

The issue is that the menu just shows until level 2, the next child levels don't show. I am using Maya template and WordPress 3.5.2

What i have to do and what file i must edit to make this work?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT

Go to wp-content/themes/templatename/ and then in header.php go to his line

```
'depth' => apply_filters( 'yiw_main_menu_depth', 3),
```

Just change the number and done!

Comment: Can you please clarify, if you have found the solution? or still looking for one?

Comment: Yes, i already find the solution. Thank you for your grammar edit anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to wp-content/themes/templatename/ and then in header.php go to his line

```
'depth' => apply_filters( 'yiw_main_menu_depth', 3),
```

Just change the number and done!